# multiple environments with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to understand the best course of action with using multiple environments, such as development, testing, production for my application with codeigniter.

As of right now I have one folder for my application. I'm seen places that talk about in the config file doing a folder for each of the environments and placing for example a copy of the database file in each of the environment folders.

Is this the best method of handling multiple environments? The reason I'm asking is because if I work on my dev subdomain I'd still have to reupload to the main root folder all the same files. Is this the best workflow?

So basically I have two sites.

dev.siteurl.com
siteurl.com

I'm trying to figure out the best option of handling this. Because I'm wondering if I'm going to just have to reupload all the files again to the main level so that it can handle the production server or is there an easier way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes the way it works is under your /application/config folder you create an extra nested folder called development so that you have

/application/config/development/

Inside development you will place a copy of your database.php file and change your development database settings

/application/config/development/database.php

THEN you have to tell codeigniter which version you are on, so in your base root folder edit index.php:

/index.php

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

When you want to use the /config/development/database.php you will change your environment to development, and when you want to use the production database you will change the environment to production

edit: also the CI TOC has a brief section explaining this: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html

Comment: So I'd have to upload all the same files and folders to the live production root?

Comment: No, whichever files you place in /application/config/development/ will override the same files in /application/config/ when you change the ENVIRONMENT variable. This is if you have a different environment for production than development(database settings etc). Is your question a workflow question?

Comment: I mean I have my dev.siteurl.com and my siteurl.com and I'd have to upload all the same files twice wouldn't I?

Comment: That's something you need to work out with workflow and integration. The easiest way to do it would be using git with post receive hooks and sending master to one folder and dev to another. So yes you would use two folders in the end but the git versioning would take care of the mess.

Comment: Well shoot. Not quite the answer I was looking for, because I still have no idea what I should be doing.

Comment: does changing enviornment takes lt of time ?? I have changed still it takes previous envio.. settings. sometimes it takes correct?? Is there could be caching issues ??

Answer (score 7):

I'm defining envirement in index.php
do something like

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='siteurl.com')
   define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
else if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='test.siteurl.com')
   define('ENVIRONMENT', 'testing');
else
   define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

and use config sections according to ENVIRONMENT variable

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but I am working on a Codeigniter project now and was looking for a good way to maintain two environments without having to maintain two codebases at two different urls.  In case anyone else is looking for a similar answer, here's a possible solution that allows you to maintain one codebase.

For my current project, I have siteurl.com and siteurl.com/sandbox.

**siteurl.com/index.php**

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

**siteurl.com/sandbox/index.php**

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
$system_path = '../../system';
$application_folder = '../../application';
```