# MySQL, PHP, Login Info correct yet "Unable to connect to the database" error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

Alright -

So this is a wee bit frustrating. I have my local Development Server and my remote Test Server. They are using identical code deployed from GitHub, including (temporarily) identical login credentials. Both Apache Servers use local MySQL Servers (for now). I have verified on both MySQL servers that the relevant user has identical permissions & passwords to a certain database.

In other words, everything is theoretically the same. EXCEPT my dev server is Windows (running XAMPP) and my Test server is Linux (running LAMP).

I am using a CodeIgniter Framework. So the problem is, my Test code runs fine on my Test box, but when I try to run it on local Dev I get the error "Unable to connect to the database". I am thinking that there must be a configuration issue between PHP & MySQL on my Dev server since I've pretty much eliminated MySQL credentials as being a possibility.

Any ideas? Much appreciated... Debbie

Answer (score 0):

[multiple environments with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328884/multiple-environments-with-codeigniter)

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html

Comment: That is not the problem. I deliberately set up a Test environment that was identical to my Development environment (as far as code and MySQL login credentials are concerned) purely to test my theory that the MySQL login credentials were *not* the cause of the DB Connection error (which is now confirmed). Therefore, I am looking for reasons why PHP might not be able to connect to MySQL DB in an XAMPP environment (other than bad userName, pwd, dbName, serverName, etc as those factors have been eliminated).

Comment: Are you sure that your mysql service is up? Can you connect from other db client? Or try phpmyadmin?