# how to separate config.php, database.php, constant.php file domain specific in codeigniter v3.1.10?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I'm using `codeigniter v3.1.10` and i have two projects with domain name `abc.example.com` and `xyz.example.com`. i know that in codeigniter according to the environment production or development we could add folders `application/config/production` and `application/config/development` in config folder with their respective files in them. An example found in SO : -[multiple environments with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328884/multiple-environments-with-codeigniter), gives us a provision to add `development/production` folders inside `application/config` folder.

But what i'm looking for is `domain specific folders inside application/config folder`. Is there a way that i could put two folders like `application/config/abc.example.com` and `application/config/xyz.example.com` with `config.php, database.php and constant.php` files in them.

Comment: yes, use your environment as `xyz.example.com` and `abc.example.com`

Comment: @jagad89 could you explain me little more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per your requirement, you want multiple subdomain configu. 
e.g for subdomain `abc.exmaple.com` want to load `abc` config folder. 
for subdomain `xyz.exmaple.com` want to load `xyz` config folder.

in your `index.php`

```
$env= 'development';
list($subdomain,$host) = explode('.', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
$allowed_subdomains = ['abc','xyz'];
$env = in_array($subdomain,$allowed_sbudomains) ? $subdomain : $env;
define('ENVIRONMENT',$env);
```

in `switch..case` below as a case for your subdomain

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
   {
     ...
     ... 
     case 'testing':
     case 'production':
     case $subdomain:
     ....
   }
```

now create a folder as per your subdomain under the config folder and do your required configuration there.

Comment: is there a way without changing the ENVIRONMENT constant.

Comment: you can manage a separate application folder for each. check [this](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html)

Comment: ok but i would like to use only one application folder but only my config.php database and constants need to be changed.

Comment: i'm getting an error `The configuration file does not exist.`

Comment: I need to check folder structure, without that can't say what's causing the issue.

Comment: the folder inside the application/config folder should be application/config/abc and application/config/xyz