# CodeIgniter 4 config files for different environments

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks, config, environment, codeigniter-4

I'm setting up a prototype application in CodeIgniter 4 and I'm totally puzzled when it comes to having different configurations for different environments. I have the concept of having different config files (or versions of them) for the different environments and keeping the framework's default config files untouched, but I don't know if that may be the appropriate approach for CI4. My main concern is if further framework updates may end changing the default config files.

I get how to use the .env files regarding DB and environment setup but I think on going further and set i.e. different locales, set up Monolog with different logs, set up different filters, etc. But I'm not familiar with the standard procedure for CI4.

I'd really appreciate some guidance with this, thanks in advance!

I've tried creating environment folders inside app/Config adapting namespaces but CI4 won't pick up the different files depending on the environment.

```
    app/
    ├── Config/
    │   ├── development/
    │   │   ├── app.php
    │   │   ├── database.php
    │   │   ├── filters.php
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── production/
    │   │   ├── app.php
    │   │   ├── database.php
    │   │   ├── filters.php
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── testing/
    │   │   ├── app.php
    │   │   ├── database.php
    │   │   ├── filters.php
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── app.php
    │   ├── database.php
    │   ├── filters.php
    │   └── ...
```

Comment: No need to change the default config directory you download. To change the environment find the .env file  and there find `CI_ENVIRONMENT` set a value of environment like  production, development. for example:  CI_ENVIRONMENT = development   if you see the # sign before this code remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your response @WebMarketingSolutionNetwork I'm aware of what you're saying but what I'm trying to find out is if there's some sort of conventional or accepted way of having like the default /Config/ files and then i.e. having a Filters.php file for developing, another Filters.php for production with different code... and this same thing for each Config file I may need to tweak.

I'm by the way not sure if CI4 is meant to work like that...

Comment: I personally don't see any practical use case for this structure. If you could state why you would need this kind of implementation, it would help others to point you in the right direction. I.e: _What kind of logic would necessitate someone to have varying configuration source code beyond basic config variables/properties?_

Comment: Thanks for your response @steven7mwesigwa the reason is that I would like to preserve the framework files untouched in case I need different setups depending on the environment or even if a framework version update modifies those files. But I don't know if that approach would be feasible in CI4. I got this hint to that implementation posted in Stack Overflow (I believe for earlier versions of CI): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328884/multiple-environments-with-codeigniter

Comment: Umm, maybe I didn't make myself clear earlier. My basic question is: _What are you currently implementing that wouldn't be achieved by simple environment variables in the `.env` file of the respective environments?_

Comment: For your information,  you would normally **not** need to manually modify/edit the framework's core configuration properties. **All** scaler and array structured configuration properties are changeable/modifiable using the environment variables in the `env` file. This special `env` file has a higher precedence over the hard-coded values in the respective configuration classes. This nullifies your concern regarding loss of settings due to a framework update. 

Comment: In addition, you may create custom configuration classes for your other settings that are outside the scope of the core framework setup. Public properties of these custom configuration classes are also changeable using the `.env` file of the respective environments.

Comment: Thanks a lot @steven7mwesigwa I believe that's what I'm looking for then. My intention is to have different sets of config classes depending on the environment but maybe my approach should be to have different .env files that override those classes and then alternate between said .env files.

Comment: You're most welcome! Yes, have alternating `.env` files whose settings will **override** the public scalar and array structured properties of your new custom and existing core config classes.  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For your information, you would normally **not** need to manually
> modify/edit the framework's core configuration properties. All scaler
> and array structured configuration properties are
> changeable/modifiable using the environment variables in the *`.env`*
> file. This special *`.env`* file has a **higher precedence** over the
> hard-coded values in the respective configuration classes. This
> nullifies your concern regarding loss of settings due to a framework
> update.

> In addition, you may create [custom configuration classes](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/configuration.html#id6) for your
> other settings that are outside the scope of the core framework setup.
> Public properties of these custom configuration classes are also
> changeable/overridable using the *`.env`* file of the respective
> environments.

##### Summary:

Have alternating `.env` files whose settings will **override** the public scalar and array structured properties of your new custom and existing core config classes.

##### Reference

[Configuration Classes and Environment Variables](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/general/configuration.html#id9)

> If the prefix of a namespaced variable exactly matches the namespace of the configuration class, then the trailing part of the setting (after the dot) is treated as a configuration property. If it matches an existing configuration property, the environment variable’s value will replace the corresponding value from the configuration file. If there is no match, the configuration class properties are left unchanged. In this usage, the prefix must be the full (case-sensitive) namespace of the class.

> ```php
> Config\App.forceGlobalSecureRequests = true
> Config\App.CSPEnabled = true
> ```

Comment: It's working, I've been editing config classes from my .env.* files successfully.

Great solution!

Comment: @DiegoAlonso Thank you very much for your positive feedback. I'm glad I could be of help. 

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a dead end regarding filters, which I find to not be possible to use without editing the framework file app/Config/Filters.php

As the .env files can't create new arrays or keys for the existing arrays in the config classes but edit their values I still need to edit the $aliases, $globals, etc. arrays from filters.php

Here's an example for a simple filter I created aliased as 'log':

```
public array $aliases = 
[
    'csrf'          => CSRF::class,
    'toolbar'       => DebugToolbar::class,
    'honeypot'      => Honeypot::class,
    'invalidchars'  => InvalidChars::class,
    'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
    'log' => LogFilter::class,
];

public array $globals = 
[
    'before' => [
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'csrf',
        // 'invalidchars',
        'log'
    ],
    'after' => [
        'toolbar',
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'secureheaders',
    ],
];
```

I can't find a workaround without editing the Filters.php file, Is it even feasible?

Thanks in advance.